# discord Add SetGame/SetStatus

Tags: c#, api, bots, discord

I would like to know how to set the " Playing  " for the bot in C#, I am using .NET

On Discord the text is usually under your name and says the current game you are playing, I want it to show a custom message, of course I know the bot is not playing a game I just want it to say something I want it to say, for example "Playing the good guy",
"Playing osu!".
"Playing Google Chrome",

This is a portion of my code, please help me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;

namespace Kosei_Arima
{
class MyBot
{
    DiscordClient discord;
    CommandService commands;

    Random rand;

    string[] freshestMemes;

    public MyBot()
    {
        rand = new Random();

        freshestMemes = new string[]
        {
            "mem/mem1.jpg", //0
            "mem/mem2.jpg", //1
            "mem/mem3.png", //2
            "mem/mem4.png", //3
            "mem/mem5.png", //4
            "mem/mem6.jpg", //5
            "mem/mem7.jpg", //6
            "mem/mem8.jpg", //7
            "mem/mem9.jpg", //8
            "mem/mem10.jpg", //9
            "mem/mem11.jpg", //10
            "mem/mem12.jpg", //11
            "mem/mem13.jpg", //12
            "mem/mem14.jpg", //13
            "mem/mem15.jpg", //14
            "mem/mem16.jpg", //15
            "mem/mem17.jpg", //16
            "mem/mem18.jpg", //17
            "mem/mem19.jpg", //18
            "mem/mem20.jpg", //19
            "mem/mem21.jpg", //20
            "mem/mem22.png"  //21
        };

        discord = new DiscordClient(x =>
        {
            x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
            x.LogHandler = Log;
        });

        discord.UsingCommands(x =>
        {
            x.PrefixChar = '-';
            x.AllowMentionPrefix = true;
        });

        commands = discord.GetService<CommandService>();

        RegisterMemeCommand();
        RegisterHelpCommand();
        RegisterPurgeCommand();
        RegisterPruneCommand();
        RegisterDisconnectCommand();
        RegisterEchoCommand();

        OnJoin();
        OnLeave();

        discord.MessageReceived += Discord_MessageReceived;

        discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
        {
            await discord.Connect("TokenGoesHere", TokenType.Bot);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the DiscordClient's `SetGameAsync(string name, string streamurl = null, StreamType streamtype = StreamType.NotStreaming)` function to do this (defaults for the arguments that have them are given). It's an async, so you'll need to await it (and all the standard things that apply to asynchronous functions apply here). If all you want to do is set the game, usage is pretty simple:

```
await discord.SetGameAsync("Google Chrome");
```

For a Twitch stream (Discord.net supports nothing else it seems):

```
await discord.SetGameAsync("Overwatch", "https://twitch.tv/yourstreamhere", 
  StreamType.Twitch);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
        client.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
        {
            await client.Connect("your fkin token is here", TokenType.Bot);
            client.SetGame("<whatever you want>");
        });
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer. Just answering with code is not always enough for the asker.